# could not load root hash from incremental install

Tags: android, android-app-bundle, android-app-signing, firebase-app-distribution

We have set up Firebase App Distribution to use our app bundle. It is signed by Google Play (play store signing using their key) after we linked to our account on the Firebase Dashboard.

When installing the app, the Firebase App Tester redirects to the Play Store app, and then fails to install with this error (in console logs):

`PackageManager  E  ERROR: could not load root hash from incremental install`

What can cause this issue? I checked related questions on SO but none provides a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved when I switched my compile SDK.

```
// compileSdkPreview = "UpsideDownCake"
compileSdk = 33
```

Credit goes to a random comment that lead me to the right track here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/231345771